# Upgrading PostgreSQL packages after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, upgrade, apt

I just upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 and then to 22.04, but my PostgreSQL packages seem did not upgrade properly.

```
root@postgres:~# apt list --installed | grep postgresql

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

postgresql-14/now 14.4-1.pgdg18.04+1 amd64 [installed,local]
postgresql-client-14/now 14.4-1.pgdg18.04+1 amd64 [installed,local]
postgresql-client-common/now 241.pgdg18.04+1 all [installed,local]
postgresql-client/jammy,now 14+238 all [installed]
postgresql-common/now 241.pgdg18.04+1 all [installed,local]
postgresql-contrib/jammy,now 14+238 all [installed]
postgresql-doc-14/jammy-updates,now 14.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
postgresql-doc/jammy,now 14+238 all [installed]
postgresql-server-dev-14/now 14.4-1.pgdg18.04+1 amd64 [installed,local]
postgresql/jammy,now 14+238 all [installed]
```

```sql
select version();

PostgreSQL 14.4 (Ubuntu 14.4-1.pgdg18.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit
```

How to upgrade them? Does it matter that I run old postgres binaries compiled for the older version of Ubuntu? Does it affect the performance?

Comment: I think I am facing a similar situation of a mesh of inhomogeneous postgres package versions, or possibly outdated or conflicting packages of postgres packages, post an upgrade to 22.04. But alas I am unsure how to interpret these apt outputs to the level of taking appropriate action.